# Maximum range in Random function in java

Tags: java, random

At this Random function in java

```
Random rndm = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
    myarray.add(i, rndm.nextInt());
    }
```

i want to know if there is no range ,what is the maximum range of Random Function for integer and for long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range is `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (`-2^31` to `2^31-1`) for `nextInt()` and is approximately `Long.MIN_VALUE` to `Long.MAX_VALUE` (`-2^63` to `2^63-1`) for `nextLong()`.

Quote from [Random (Java Platform SE 8 )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

> public int nextInt()
>
> [...] All 2<sup>32</sup> possible int values are produced with (approximately) equal probability.
>
> [...]
>
> public long nextLong()
>
> [...]
>
> The method nextLong is implemented by class Random as if by:
>
> ```
> public long nextLong() {
>   return ((long)next(32) << 32) + next(32);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

According to java docs.

```
random.nextInt()
```

Returns the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value from this random number generator's sequence. So the maximum will be the limit of `int`, which is `2^31-1`

If you want to set a bound you can use `nextInt(int bound)`
. Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

For long, max value is `2^63-1`

Answer (score 0):

You can find more details from [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Random.java/?v=source)

```
public int nextInt() {
    return next(32);
}

    /*
     * @param n the bound on the random number to be returned.  Must be
     *        positive.
     * @return the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed {@code int}
     *         value between {@code 0} (inclusive) and {@code n} (exclusive)
     *         from this random number generator's sequence
     * @exception IllegalArgumentException if n is not positive
     * @since 1.2
     */
public int nextInt(int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");

    if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
        return (int)((n * (long)next(31)) >> 31);

    int bits, val;
    do {
        bits = next(31);
        val = bits % n;
    } while (bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
    return val;
}
```